# Error while installing SQL Server 2008 on Windows 7 Home Edition 64 bit

Tags: sql-server-2008, windows-7, 64-bit

I am trying to install SQL Server 2008 on my Windows 7 Home Edition,

Setup is giving an error

> attempting to perform unauthorized operation

Comment: http://www.phwinfo.com/forum/ms-sqlserver-setup/320374-sql-2008-install-fail-attempted-perform-unauthorized-opera.html

Comment: have you tried the registry fix linked by juergen?

Answer (score 0):

Try running the installation "as administrator".

Comment: i have already tried that

Answer (score 0):

[Step To Install :)](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/06/12/sql-server-2008-step-by-step-installation-guide-with-images/)

hope this will help you to install  :)

Answer (score 0):

First extract the files to a folder on the C drive using the command prompt, e.g.:

```
SQLEXPR_x64_ENU -x
```

Then run the program as admin. This worked for me.